# Ahead-of-time validation of TypeScript in existing Javascript project

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to get the ahead of time validation feature of TypeScript to work in a pure JavaScript project? I would install TypeScript but it honestly seems a bit intimidating and useless for my purposes.

Comment: There is a reason TS is an entire language of its own. You can't really pick one thing from it and use it elsewhere. You can use Flow (also a language with a type system) or things like Tern.js (some of editors have this or similar built in) that works on JS code. But you still need annotations either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable type checking in a Javascript project just by using a `tsconfig.json` file. No need to actually compile Typescript files.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built",
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```